# Javascript error - Touchstart - [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following error in the console referencing my mobile swipe script.

```sh
Error: [Violation] 
    Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. 
    Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
class Swipe {
    constructor(element) {
        this.xDown = null;
        this.yDown = null;
        this.element = typeof(element) === 'string' ? document.querySelector(element) : element;

        this.element.addEventListener('touchstart', function(evt) {
            this.xDown = evt.touches[0].clientX;
            this.yDown = evt.touches[0].clientY;
        }.bind(this), false);
    }
```

I ran across another article on this site that said to add the following:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handler, {passive: true});
```

I've tried every possible way to implement this code into what I have with no success. When I try to add this statement it breaks my slider.

How would I go about adding this or inserting it into what I have already?

Comment: `When I try to add this statement it breaks my slider` how? Can you create a working snippet? Afaik, the only effect of `{passive: true}` that the browser ignores `event.preventDefault`. Is it needed un your code?

Comment: @Thom can you help producing an [MCVE] here? Without it this question can not be answered, doing what's written in it should *just work™*. https://jsfiddle.net/d3zLatg9/

Comment: Is this actually a linter error? I've only seen warnings in browsers when preventing the default in an event marked with `passive: true` (which Chrome and FF do automatically if specifically not set to `false` on specific events and targets). On all of that, even a linter error, it's a false positive.

Comment: I guess its break your Swipe because the listener start working, and you start running into next problem. your listener defined as a `function`, means the `this` inside point to the function, not the Slider object. try change the listener to be an arrow function (`(e)=>{...}`)